# How to find out the sampling rate of an acceleration sensor?

Tags: sensors, frequency-response

In the sensor catalogs, I cannot find this field. They only depict the frequency response range. For example, Bently Nevada's sensors. How we can find out their maximum sampling rate?

Comment: A very quick look shows that acceleration transducers from Bently Nevada are voltage-output devices. So you would have to go through the 'usual' filter-and-ADC design exercise, to prevent aliasing, get the useful resolution you need without quantization noise etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an analog accelerometer, you can try to sample as often as you'd like. It's up to the data acquisition card, if it can catch up. Of course you probably won't get useful data.

For digital accelerometers the documentation should provide the maximum sampling frequency.

---

The maximum **useful** frequency is another matter. The following diagram shows the response of an accelerometer and the useful ranges (in log scale).

[image]

**figure: Frequency range of accelerometer (source: [Dubravko Miljković](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/304094143_Brief_Review_of_Vibration_Based_Machine_Condition_Monitoring/figures?lo=1))**

Essentially you are trying to be on the flat portion of the sensitivity.